# SQL query don't work , convert string to date on PHP

Tags: php, string, date, extract

I would like to check the expiry date that a user entered in the format: "YY-MM" string, I get this date and I get the card with the expiry date, the query works perfectly under the console phpmyadmin, but as soon as I switch to php, the result I expected is null. Here is the code under the SQL console

```
SELECT  
    numero_carte,cvv, cc.numero_compte , email
FROM
    carte_credit as cc, compte as cp
WHERE
    numero_carte="*****"
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_expiration) = 2019
    AND EXTRACT(MONTH from date_expiration) = 12
    AND cc.numero_compte = Cp.numero_compte ;
```

This worked on the SQL console but when I use prepared query like :

```
$moiExp=substr($dateExp,0,2);  // on converti en int pour pouvoir comparer dans la condition de la requete juste au dessous
$annExp="20".substr($dateExp,3,2); // on concatene pour avoir une annee de format 2019 en int

$reqA= $bdd->prepare("SELECT  numero_carte,cvv, cc.numero_compte , email
                               from carte_credit as cc, compte as cp
                                where numero_carte=?
                                AND  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_expiration ) =?
                                AND  EXTRACT(MONTH from date_expiration) = ?
                                AND  cc.numero_compte = Cp.numero_compte ");
$reqA->execute(array($NumCarteAcheteur,$annExp,$moiExp));
```

in this case the result is null , i tried everything , but i think there is a problem with date formats.

Comment: Ermm... did you just post somebody's credit card number on the Internet?

Comment: Note this also violates PCI DSS. You can not store unprotected card numbers and you can **absolutely not** store CVV. This is a good way to get fined and have your ability to process cards revoked.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your month year extraction is backwards

```
$dateExp='18-10';//yy-mm

$moiExp=substr($dateExp,3,2); //=10
$annExp="20".substr($dateExp,0,2); //=2018
```

an alternative, would be to `explode()` on the hyphen this might be easier if the dates (month) could be 1 or 2 digits

```
$e=explode('-',$dateExp);
$moiExp=$e[0];
$annExp="20".$e[1];
```

I hope this is some kind of school project because you should not be storing credit card numbers without being pci compliant.